# How does table contain case when column default logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Dummy example: If I want id mod 2 to be 1 then mark the Type as odd, otherwise even, and I tried to use the following SQL

```sql
create table T (
    ID id,
    Type varchar(4) default case when id % 2 = 1 then 'odd' else 'even' end
)
```

But will get the following error

```
Msg 128 Level 15 State 1 Line 3
The name "id" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
```

I can do this with constant, but it lose `dynamic` charactor

```sql
create table T (
    ID int,
    Type varchar(4) default case when 1 % 2 = 1 then 'odd' else 'even' end
)
```

[Online Test SQL Server 2017 | db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1dda88dff15641aeb121ac455bb5898d)

Comment: You want a computed column, not a default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15) like below.

```
create table T (
    ID int,
    Type AS case when 1 % 2 = 1 then 'odd' else 'even' end
)
```

[Computed columns actually are virtual columns that are not physically stored in the table unless the column is marked `PERSISTED`.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/computed-columns-in-sql-server/)
Thus if you want your column to be stored physically then use `PERSISTED` as below.

```
create table T (
    ID int,
    Type AS case when 1 % 2 = 1 then 'odd' else 'even' end PERSISTED
)
```